# How to manage IDE project files on a forked repository

Tags: version-control, git

I recently forked a Git repository, and locally I created a project in my IDE to compile with.

My IDE creates a variety of artifacts that I would like to keep saved somewhere. The obvious place would be in the VCS. If I add these files then they will be in the history for my fork. If i want send a pull request to merge upstream I wouldn't want these files included.

What would be a recommended workflow for managing these changes that I would never want to go upstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structure your project so that it sits in a directory (and builds all files) outside of the source directory (such as [project root]/build) and exclude that directory in .gitignore.

This is the process that CMake uses (see ["out-of-source builds" in their docs](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F)). Of course, you could always introduce yourself to CMake and build it into the project's pipeline. I'm sure the authors would love you for it ;)

Comment: yeah, gitignore on the "out-of-source" files is what I have currently.